# Get element value from web page using jQuery $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following script that grabs all the contents from my Intranet Home Page and displays it on a page.

I was wondering, is it possible to just get the value inside this element `<div id="username">my.username</div>` that is on my home page?

**Current Code:**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('http://intranet', function(data){ 
    $(data).appendTo(document.body); 
    //$('#username').attr('id')
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is the `#username` tag inside the data?

Comment: Try with URL `'http://intranet #username'`

Comment: why not go for iframe and src

Comment: @KARASZIIstván Inside the home page HTML is `<div id="username">my.username</div>`

Comment: @Satpal I have tried this, but it just pulls the entire page again and not specifically the value inside my `username` div.

Comment: @ABUdhay Do you have an example of this? :)

Comment: just refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then this should work:

```
$.get('http://intranet', function(data){ 
    var username = $('#username', data).text();
    alert(username);
});
```